# Nintendo Switch left Joy-Con disconnects frequently. Fix?

Tags: hardware, nintendo-switch

When playing Zelda: Breath of the Wilds on the Nintendo Switch, when I play with the Switch docked and the Joy-Cons physically disconnected, the left Joy-Con frequently "lags" or becomes disconnected from the Switch base unit altogether.

When the left Joy-Con lags, the Switch acts as though whatever input I had been using was still being held down.  For example, Link will occasionally keep running briefly even after I release the analog joystick.

Only the left Joy-Con has this issue.  The right Joy-Con always stays connected and has no lag issues.

The issue doesn't occur when the Joy-Cons are attached to the Nintendo Switch base unit itself.

The left Joy-Con does seem to work ok when it is within about 3 feet of the Nintendo Switch base unit, and there is no line-of-sight obstruction between the Joy-Con and the Switch

I have applied the "day one patch" to the Switch, with the Joy-Cons connected to the base Switch unit as the patch was applied.

Upon researching, this issue is has been widely reported on gaming news sites. (Refs: [1](http://kotaku.com/switch-owners-are-still-reporting-joy-con-connectivity-1792928040), [2](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/nintendo-switch-joy-con-issues-and-other-tidbits-a/1100-6448415/), [3](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-2017-switch-joy-cons-tested-are-there-really-de-sync-issues))

There's also an [article on the Nintendo Support site](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22513/p/897/c/715) about general Joy-Con wireless connectivity problems.  However, that article doesn't make any mention of the problem specific to the left Joy-Con.

My question: How can I resolve this intermittent wireless connectivity problem with the left Joy-Con?

Comment: [Ars Technica's review](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2017/03/nintendo-switch-review/) also reported this issue, but the reviewer said that it only happened when docked. "I've only had this happen when the system is docked to a TV that is roughly seven to 10 feet from the controllers—it never happens when the system is merely propped on its kickstand, when the controllers tend to be much closer." So a short-term fix may be to just play in the undocked mode.

Comment: [Nintendo's official troubleshooting](http://kotaku.com/nintendo-advises-switch-owners-with-joy-con-connectivit-1792952354):  Avoid aquariums, other wireless devices like routers and wireless speakers, and putting the Switch behind something.

Comment: @TimmyJim - Yep, linked to original version of that article in the 2nd-to-last paragraph of the question above. That advice helps *somewhat*, but it really shouldn't be necessary: None of my other wireless controllers in the same room have similar issues, including the right Joy-Con, various Wii U controllers, and various Xbox controllers!

Comment: The other alternative is to purchase the Nintendo Pro Controller, which I did today after having Link mysteriously walk straight off a mountain without me doing anything at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known design flaw](http://www.trustedreviews.com/news/nintendo-may-have-solved-switch-joy-con-desync-issue-with-foam) which is only effecting early models of the Switch.

It's something to do with electrical shielding (or something technical).
[image: Left Joy Con with and without shielding]

First try these steps to make sure you are using the Joy Con correctly

[Joy Con Not Responding or Responding Incorrectly When Used Wirelessly](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22513)

If that didn't work, talk to Nintendo and they will "[fix your problem for free](https://www.cnet.com/news/nintendo-switch-joycon-desync-connectivity-issue-fix/)" - which means you send in your joy con and they fix it and send it back. This can take up to 2 weeks.

Here are some helpful links for support:

[Contact Nintendo Support in America](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/547)

[Contact Nintendo Support in Australia and New Zealand](http://www.nintendo.com.au/warranty)

[Contact Nintendo Support in Europe](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Contact/Repairs/General-Customer-Service-1106617.html)

Answer (score 5):

I have exactly same issue. Left JoyCon, lag most of the time, sometimes disconnects. Try to sit close to the console (like 1 meter) - this seems to helps a little but even then it happens every now and then.

Otherwise you might want to consider exchanging to a different Switch console in the shop.

Answer (score 3):

The Left JoyCon does seem to have some connectivity issues. I sit at least 6' away from my console without any problem. (Probably farther.)

- Nintendo has said to be sure the JoyCon has line of sight to the console. (Make sure there is nothing between you and the console, like a blanket or table.)
- They have also released an update to the Switch to help correct this issue. Make sure your Switch is connected to the internet and check for system updates.
- Finally, Nintendo says it will replace JoyCons if need be. They may have you go through a [few troubleshooting steps](https://www.reddit.com/r/nintendo/comments/5xqpvu/psa_nintendo_will_replace_malfunctioning_left_joy/) first.

Nintendo also released a list of devices that might cause signal interference:

- Cell phones, laptops, tablets, etc.
- Wireless headsets
- Wireless printers
- Microwaves
- Wireless speakers
- Cordless phones USB
- 3.0-compatible devices such as hard drives, thumb drives, LAN adapters, etc.

Comment: I think Wi-Fi routers and modems were listed too.