# Were the Switch's left Joy-Con connection issues ever fixed?

Tags: hardware, nintendo-switch

When the Nintendo Switch launched in February, there were [multiple](http://kotaku.com/switch-owners-are-still-reporting-joy-con-connectivity-1792928040) [articles](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/nintendo-switch-joy-con-issues-and-other-tidbits-a/1100-6448415/) [and](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-2017-switch-joy-cons-tested-are-there-really-de-sync-issues) [reviews](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22513/~/joy-con-not-responding-or-responding-incorrectly-when-used-wirelessly) claiming that the Switch's left Joy-Con was prone to frequent connection issues during normal use. (See *[Nintendo Switch left Joy-Con disconnects frequently. Fix?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/302016/181240)*)

[image: Blue-colored Left Joycon]

I've seen some claim the disconnect issue was [fixed by a day-one patch](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/5x2wbf/day_one_update_really_fixes_the_joycon_connection/?st=J4DDCKQ0&sh=5288bb69), while others claim it was a [hardware issue only present in early Switch models](http://www.trustedreviews.com/news/nintendo-may-have-solved-switch-joy-con-desync-issue-with-foam).

[image: 'Repairing' left joycon]

**Were the connection issues for the Switch's left Joy-Con ever fixed? If they were, how can I tell if my Joy-Con could be affected?**

Answer (score 4):

It has been fixed, though if you have a very early release model of the joycons, you may need to send in your left joycon for repair. I've found they respond quickly and also shipped the joycon back to me in under 3 days. Nintendo requires that you go through [this list of troubleshooting tips](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22513) before they will commit to repairing the joycon.

As for determining whether or not yours has the problem, [this GameExplain video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbG3F9RwlcY) explains how to test it - it involves going into the "calibrate control sticks" option, and waving your hand or other solid objects in between the joycon and the Switch console to see if it is affected.

Comment: Is there a serial number to check for an older joycon-revision that may be affected?

Comment: Unaccepting because joycon drift is still an issue in 2022.