# Left Joy Con's Stick Decalibrates easily when I play Fortnite

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, nintendo-switch

This started around 2 weeks ago, when I noticed my Fortnite Character was moving on its own. I knew my joy stick was decalibrated so I went In settings and Calibrated my joy stick.

But, after another match or even during the first match after I calibrated my Joy-stick, I sometimes experience slow mouvements of my character when I dont touch the joy con.

I **Think** this is caused when I press and hold the Joy-Stick and go up.(This causes my Fortnite Character to sprint Fowards).

Am I using the joy stick inappropriately or what solutions could I use to stop this 
?

Comment: Sounds like a variation of the [left joycon desync issue](https://www.vg247.com/2017/03/22/fixing-switchs-left-joy-con-desync-issue-could-be-as-simple-as-a-black-piece-of-foam/) from back when the console launched.  Does the left joycon misbehave when playing any other titles?

Comment: Sometimes at the home menu its hard to go up a block cause the controller is decalibrated slighty down. This isnt a sync issue, this is a decalibrated issue. I havent tried other games, But if it does that on the main menu, it must on other titles

Comment: My friend is also experiencing this issue, so I know this isnt rare.

Comment: @Steve-O (This comment is to notify you)

Comment: Both my joy-cons _occasionally_ disconnect durrimg gameplay, BUT that is NOT my question. My joy sticks decailbrate easily. Im pretty sure I should send it to repair cause Warranty is 1 year.

Comment: @GamerM It's not the exact same issue, granted, but it sounds like something similar and may have a common root cause.  I'd recommend sending it in for repair, yes.

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Coomie's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue with the [Nintendo switch's left joy stick](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/311912/were-the-switchs-left-joy-con-connection-issues-ever-fixed). Get in touch with Nintendo and they should help you replace it.